# Will the coin in the middle of the two opposite charges affect the equipotential lines?

Tags: electric-fields

The image shows a coin with neutral charge in between two opposite charges.[image]

Comment: Think of the coin as a "dielectric" in between the plates of a capacitor

Answer (score 1):

If coin is a conductor then it will bend the equipotential lines around it's periphery.It's neutral but still positive and negative charges will separate under the coin itself.

Answer (score 0):

The coin may have a net zero (neutral) charge on it but there will be charge separation due to induction.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the coin in the middle of the two opposite charges affect the equipotential lines?

Yes. If the plates extended infinitely, then the equipotential surfaces would be planes parallel to the plates. When the plates are not infinite, there is "fringing", but between the plates themselves, the equipotential surfaces will be approximately parallel to the plates.

Now add a coin in between. The entire coin constitutes an equipotential volume. So, any equipotential surfaces that used to pass through that volume need to bend around between the coin and the nearest plate.

I found an image at [MIT](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter5/5.8.html) that shows how the equipotential lines will bend as described above.

[image]

The equipotential lines in the image are those without arrows and running more or less vertically.